# Usar require ou chamar diretamente o arquivo *.php

Tags: php

Atualmente meu projeto está seguindo a seguinte estrutura.

```
    // SESSAO
if(($SisFuncoes->verificaPermissaoSecao($secao, 'home')) || $secao == null){
    // requerindo a home do site.
    require("html_home.php");        
}
elseif($SisFuncoes->verificaPermissaoSecao($secao, 'cadastrar')){
    require("html_cadastrar.php");
}
//.
//.
//.    
elseif($SisFuncoes->verificaPermissaoSecao($secao, 'admin_usuarios', 3)){
    require("html_admin_usuarios.php");
}
elseif($SisFuncoes->verificaPermissaoSecao($secao, 'questionario', 1)){
    require("html_questionario.php");
}        
else{
    // requerindo a home do site.
    require("html_home.php");
}
```

Essas validações estão no arquivo index.php assim a navegação do usuário é feita através `secao=questionario, secao=cadastrar`..., sendo assim a navegação por todo site e feita sem acessar diretamente as outras páginas somente com o uso do require.

Isso é em vez de usar o require e trabalhar com uso de `"$PHP_SELF/secao=cadastrar"` pensei em algo parecido com o exemplo: "$PHP_SELF/cadatrar.php" utilizando segundo modo realizarei o acesso diretamente ao arquivo.php

A minha dúvida é qual me traria um melhor desempenho, manter o acesso somente ao index.php com a utilização do require ou o acesso direto aos arquivos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O padrão hoje em dia é usar URL amigável (`site.com/nome_da_secao/nome_do_recurso`). Pra fazer isso, é parecido sim com o que você está fazendo: todos os endereços acessam um ponto inicial (o index.php) e ele decide o que vai exibir.

Do ponto de vista de performance, não sei dizer. Imagino que não tenha nenhum ganho razoável, por que tem código que você vai precisar executar antes de qualquer conteúdo, então as páginas separadas teriam algum `require` no topo de qualquer forma.

Do ponto de vista de facilitar manutenção, o que você está fazendo é bem melhor, por que você concentra a execução nesse ponto inicial sempre, ao invés de ter vários pontos iniciais no sistema todo. Se forem 10 páginas, nem tem tanto problema, mas se forem 40 já complica bastante, imagina se você resolve que algumas das páginas vão executar um acesso ao banco de dados e outras não, aí você vai ficar naquele mar de includes malucos e desnecessários, sua vida fica um inferno.

Eu, pessoalmente, gosto bastante de usar um micro-framework chamado Fat-Free-Framework que já vem com um esquema de rotas que facilita pra caramba esse fluxo de trabalho. https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/home

Só é bom lembrar que ao usar um router desses você precisa ativar o ModRewrite no Apache (ou no .htaccess) e mandar ele sempre executar o index.php

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Comment: Sua resposta é realmente muito boa. Um framework com rotas sempre me parece uma opção de manutenção muito melhor que um monte de includes.

Comment: Rapais muito obrigado, pela dica do F3 ainda to estudando esse framework, vou tentar ir estudando e postando publicando os conteúdos para ajudar a comunidade.

Comment: De nada brother. Só um adendo: eu tive vários errinhos ao usar o Mapper dele em um banco SQL Server 2003, então fica ligado que eles não são mega compatíveis. Fora isso, que bom que está ajudando a comunidade. Eu mesmo tinha que dar uma força pra eles, por que me ajuda muito essa framework.

Comment: @Daniel Estou estudando toda essa framework to percebendo que tem muitos erros com relação a documentação dela e consequentemente ficando preocupado com relação as funcionalidades dela. por exemplo a função `$f3->parse();` que simplesmente não funciona.

Comment: Opa, sim, como falei tem seus problemas. No final, é open-source, então a solução é participar do desenvolvimento quando perceber que alguma coisa não funciona. Claro, existem muitas outras micro-frameworks por aí (Silex, Slim, etc...) então não precisa ficar preso nessa. Essa função parse eu nunca usei, mas vale dar uma olhada no código fonte talvez.